# Add type run on toolbar Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I delete, for error, 'type run' (debug and release) on the toolbar on VS 2012.
I would you like to see it again on the toolbar.
How can I do?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a small down-arrow at the end of the toolbar with a "Reset" command on. Alternatively go Tools > Customize > Commands > Toolbar: Standard > Reset All.

Comment: So, on Toolbar 'Standard' exist 'DebugType', and this is selected and I view it on toolbar. But this is disabled and don't view debug/release.
Why?

Comment: I resolved !!
go Tools > Customize > Commands > Toolbar: Standard > Debug Target